# VB.NET unwanted extra break

Tags: vb.net

I have the code below;

```
Dim orderlist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
For i As Integer = 0 To newacctlist.Items.Count - 1
    orderlist.Add("This order will be placed on" & newacctlist.Items(i))
Next (i)
Textbox1.Lines = orderlist.ToArray
```

When I import items from txt file, as result, 1st i comes out correct, but the next ones get an unwanted break. They come out as:

```
This order will be placed on
Monday
```

instead of

```
This order will be placed on Monday
```

Import from txt file

```
Dim a As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(path & "\neworder.txt")
Dim b As String() = a.Split(vbNewLine)
newacctlist.Items.AddRange(b)
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

trim it,

```
orderlist.Add("This order will be placed on" & newacctlist.Items(i).Trim  )
---------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that you have a `newline`-character in your `newacctlist`-items.

Put a breakpoint on the `orederlist.Add()` line and check those values.

Also take a look at the code where you create the `newacctlist`. 
Probably your culprit is there.

** Edit **

Your split on vbNewLine includes it in the string.

```
Dim a As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(path & "\neworder.txt")
Dim b As String() = a.Split(vbNewLine)
For Each s As String In b
    Console.WriteLine(s.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, ""))
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, Trim did the job but I will try this as well